# How to create an highlight animation when a control gets focused

Tags: javascript, css, html

I would like to create a hightlight html inputs when they get focused using css and javascript, and jump through inputs highlighting the corners.

What I mean, is, when a text input get focused a quarter frame (L) locate in each corner, and when another input get focused those (L)s moves through the form to locate in the new focused control

I wanted to publish an image but I haven´t enough reputation points

Could anyone lead me how to do it?

Thanks

Comment: Please use http://google.com

Comment: $('element').focus(function() { //Your Code }); - Not working ?

Comment: Why would it work? nothing about jQuery has been discussed here?

Comment: When you say "move through" do you mean your want it to cycle though the inputs in sequence? If on input 1 and clicking input 5 it highlights 1-4 in turn and ends up on 5?

Comment: What I mean, is, when a text input get focused a quarter frame (L) locate in each corner, and when another input get focused those (L)s moves through the form to locate in the new focused control, something like http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/809/kpnt.png

Comment: Well that's moving into animation it seems, so you will definitely need some javascript

Comment: I could do it myself but I cannot post my answer because I have less than 10 reputation points :(, How can I get some points????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could do it myself!!!

First you have to draw the four corner´s highlights on HTML:

```
<img id="clt" src="img/clt.png" border="0" style="position:absolute;visibility:hidden"></span>
<img id="crt" src="img/crt.png" border="0" style="position:absolute;visibility:hidden"></span>
<img id="crb" src="img/crb.png" border="0" style="position:absolute;visibility:hidden"></span>
<img id="clb" src="img/clb.png" border="0" style="position:absolute;visibility:hidden"></span>
```

After, create a JavaScript function:

```
function getFocusFunct(){
    $("input[type=text], input[type=password], textarea").focus(function(){
        var ctl=$(this);
        var offset=ctl.offset();

        var clt=$("#clt");
        var crt=$("#crt");
        var crb=$("#crb");
        var clb=$("#clb");

        clt.css('visibility','visible');
        crt.css('visibility','visible');
        crb.css('visibility','visible');
        clb.css('visibility','visible');

        clt.animate({top:offset.top-3, left:offset.left-3}, 150);
        crt.animate({top:offset.top-3, left:offset.left+ctl.outerWidth()-4}, 150);
        crb.animate({top:offset.top+ctl.outerHeight()-4,left:offset.left+ctl.outerWidth()-4}, 150);
        clb.animate({top:offset.top+ctl.outerHeight()-4,left:offset.left-3}, 150);
    });
    $("input[type=text], input[type=password], textarea").blur(function(){
        clt.css('visibility','hidden');
        crt.css('visibility','hidden');
        crb.css('visibility','hidden');
        clb.css('visibility','hidden');
    });
}
```

It´s super awesome effect!!! Try it :)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you have to use javascript for some reason, but you can handle focus highlighting with just plain CSS.

```
input[type="text"]:focus, 
textarea:focus, 
select:focus
{
    border-color:#0cf;
    /* etc... */
}
```

That will color/highlight the borders of the input

simple, clean

EDIT:

[image]

I imagine it can be done, but its more than my CSS skills cover.

My only CSS thoughts are some kind of [Gradient](http://css-tricks.com/examples/GradientBorder/) but I don't think you can gradient an outline, just borders. And you have wont have full browser coverage.

You might be able to do something with [:before and :after](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2011/07/13/learning-to-use-the-before-and-after-pseudo-elements-in-css/) by dropping an image left and right.

Javascript wise there is a [Malsup plugin](http://www.malsup.com/jquery/corner/) that you can look at, but nothing that will match exactly that image.

Comment: Maybe I didn´t explain good enough what I want to create.

Comment: You can do other decorations via CSS if you didn't want to highlight borders. I just gave that as a syntax example.  You could affect just one corner, use radius and such.

Comment: Maybe I didn´t explain good enough what I want to create. What I want is, when a text input get focused a quarter frame (L) locate in each corner, and when another input get focused those (L)s moves through the form to locate in the new focused control

Comment: Are you saying you want to dog-ear the corner on focus, or is that a literal "L" you want to super-impose? How bought' uploading an example picture to imageshack and linking?

Comment: http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/809/kpnt.png